# Why is this UIButton not being initialized at the moment I call the init method at its super view?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I'm working with a view controller that I created (MyViewController) that has a UIButton called "button", this is the code that I've been trying to get it to work:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
MyViewController *myViewController=[[[MyViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
[myViewController.button addTarget:self action:@selector(action) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
return footerController.view;
}
```

I'm not sure what's wrong with it, but apparently I can fix it if I do this:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
MyViewController *myViewController=[[[MyViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
[myViewController.view addSubview:nil];
[myViewController.button addTarget:self action:@selector(action) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
return footerController.view;
}
```

Can someone please tell me why is this happening? And is there a way around this, because I don't think it's ok to do that..

Answer (score 0):

The nib is not loaded until it is needed to save memory, as signaled by the `view` property being accessed. If possible, it would be better to do that sort of initialization in MyViewController's `viewDidLoad` method.

Answer (score 0):

What Anomie said is right.. I found the way around it.. I can't access the button directly with `myViewController.button`, instead I have to use the method: `[myViewController.view viewWithTag:buttonTag]`. That way I'm making sure the button has already been initialized.